# React useEffect trigger conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm moving over to functional components from class components and having trouble handling this scenario. This component's state can be updated by 2 different event listeners: key down or mouseover. I want to trigger a callback after the state is updated ONLY if updated by key down. Any way to do this?

```
const handleMouseOver = e => {
  setSelection(e.target.value)
}

const handleDownArrowKeyDown = () => {
   ...
   setSelection(selection + 1)
}

useEffect(() => {
   // Only execute below if selection state was updated by handleDownArrowKeyDown
   ...
}, [selection])
```

Answer (score 1):

Put that code inside `handleDownArrowKeyDown` instead - accounting for the new selection number.

```
const handleMouseOver = e => {
    setSelection(e.target.value)
}

const handleDownArrowKeyDown = () => {
    setSelection(newSelection)
    const newSelection = selection + 1;
    // stuff that relies on newSelection
}
```

Comment: No guarantee that will execute after the state has been set.

Comment: Indeed, it definitely won't execute after the state has been set - rather, it'll definitely execute before the state has been set, which is why you need `// stuff that relies on newSelection` rather than an effect hook.